# Angular 2.4, Webpack 2.2.1, Is Lazy Loading Possible?

Tags: angular2-routing

I am creating a very simple Angular 2.4 application and no matter what I try I cannot get a Module to lazy load. Is it at all possible please?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'schedule', loadChildren: 'app/schedule/schedule.module.ts#ScheduleModule' },
{ path: 'plant', loadChildren: 'app/plant/plant.module.ts#PlantModule' }
];
```